# Calling Asynctask in a queue

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on an app and want to send some data to server. I was able to send the data to server when the updates that I was sending to server were periodic.

But now Its upon user interaction. I have to send 1 or more calls to server. I cant skip and omit any call towards server. Just suppose the following case:

**Case:**

Let say I have a button on its click I launch a asyntask that put some data on server and let suppose it takes 5 to 6 seconds. But I want to trigger multiple asyntask , if user press the button multiple time. Let suppose he presses the button 7 time in a row. so the 7 AsyncTask must run in a queue one after an other.

I have heard about schedular and all others but I am unable to understand how to work with them using asynctask as well.

**Possible solution :**  I can disable button until and unless first Async task is not completed, But I really do not want to do it, because under the requirements and needs I have to call async task as many times as user presses the button.

please help me, any source code will be appreciated.

**Note: With asynctask I have nothing to update the UI.**

**Update :**

under my need I want to queue the asynctask with specific data and it must automatically run when the previous task is completed and if user exit the application it should continue running until and unless it completes the execution of all queued asynctask.

Comment: you want to run simultaneously ?

Comment: under my need I want to queue the asynctask with specific data and it must automatically run when the previous task is completed and if user exit the application it should continue running until and unless it completes the execution of all queued asynctask.

Comment: Then you must add these things also in your question. please edit your question

Comment: You do not have to do anything. They will already run one after the other. Didnt you perceive?

Comment: What you can do is use an int variable that tracks the amount of clicks pressed by the user then during your Asynctask `onPostExecute()` method, check to see if lastCount is equals to the clickedCount, if not relaunch same asynctask instance. N/B: you must increment the lastCount if the are not equal.

Comment: thanks for you such ideas, I already have some sort of these adjustments and ideas but I really wanted to know if there is anything more good then asynctask that handls all this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let suppose he presses the button 7 time in a row. so the 7 AsyncTask must run in a queue one after an other.

Depending on what API your app target you may simply need to do nothing special. [Official documentation reads:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> **Order of execution**
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed
>   serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was
>   changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in
>   parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single
>   thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution

therefore starting from Android 3.0 `execute()` is all you need really, which means unless you support ancient versions of the platform you should be seeing serial execution by default.

Alternatively, you can drop AsyncTask in favor of IntentService which are executed one after another.

Comment: I have tested it, let it runing all aysnctask together let say If I click button twice, I have noticed that they gets hang up and takes more time then usuall

Comment: not sure what `more than usual` means and how you measured it but the question was how to run AsyncTasks one by one. And I answered just that. Alternatively nothing prevents you from writting your own queue to manage the provided solutions (inl. IntentService) are not fitting your needs. But that's off scope of your current question.